# Why binutils or gcc is installed in two locations?

Tags: linux, gcc, binutils

I'm learning linux knowledges, when I compile binutils or gcc and install them, they always appear in two locations.

I think it must be a reason and I don't know why?

Actually I'm learning lfs. When I compile the pass I of binutils, the book's instructions is:

```
../binutils-2.22/configure     \
    --prefix=/tools            \
    --with-sysroot=$LFS        \
    --with-lib-path=/tools/lib \
    --target=$LFS_TGT          \
    --disable-nls              \
    --disable-werror
```

After I `make` && `make install`, it is installed in two locations: `/tools/bin` and `/tools/$LFS_TGT/bin`.

I want to why and the purpose of doing that.

Comment: Which locations are you talking about? The default prefix when configuring `gcc` or `binutils` is `/usr/local/` but most Linuxes use `/usr/` as the prefix of their installed `gcc`, so the system binary is in `/usr/bin/gcc` but a default configured manually-compiled `gcc` build tree put it in `/usr/local/bin/gcc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, the binary that is in `/tools/$LFS_TGT/bin` is the version of the tool that is specifically built for that particular `$LFS_TGT`. A second copy is placed in `/tools/$LFS_TGT`, because the tool is intended to replace the one that is already present there because you told it to do that using the `--with-sysroot` option